# Java7 Cartesian Product versia without duplicates

Tags: java, java-7

Assuming I have a `set<Integer>` (few thousands). 
I want to perform cartesian product but without any duplicates.

A duplicate entry is considered to have the inverse element in the set (i.e. `<1,3>` and `<3,1>` are considered duplicates).

How can I do it efficiently?

First I use `Sets.cartesianProduct(set, set)` which results ~22M elements, but it also contained duplications. iterating that list again to check `result.contains(..)` is not efficient at all.

Comment: Do you have the option to switch from `set<Integer>` to something you can sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny, I've been messing around with this for few hours, and the moment I write a question in Stackoverflow, I suddenly realize the answer myself ;)

**Edited following @DmitryGorkovets improvement**

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < list.size(); j++) {
        result.add(new Pair<>(list.get(i), list.get(j)));
    }
}
```

Comment: You can start from `i+1` for j. In this case you should not check `i==j`.

Comment: You didn't specify, but I presume `list` is a sorted list of your set?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou actually It doesn't. why should it matter?

Comment: You're right, it shouldn't matter if they are sorted or not. As long as your original set is converted to a list so that you can use `get(i)`.